# Is it possible to fwrite from specific starting index in C?

Tags: c, fwrite

For example,

```
    char ch[50] = "ABCDEFGH";
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt","w");
    fwrite(ch,1,6,fp);
```

this codes writes "ABCDEF" to the file. But I need to write "BCDEFG" to the file. It will be perfect if that can be done without making any substring.

Comment: `fwrite(ch + 1, 1, 6, fp)`

Comment: Read [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: Do you want to write BCDEFG in next iteration after writing ABCDEF?

Answer (score 2):

Remember, in C, strings are just pointers to their starting character. Just do `ch+1` in place of `ch` and it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Strings are not pointers. A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its starting character.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write `BCDEFG` from the same string, just pass a pointer to the second byte of the array `ch` to `fwrite`:

```
char ch[50] = "ABCDEFGH";
FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
if (fp != NULL) {
    fwrite(ch + 1, 1, 6, fp);
    ...
}
```

Note that you can also use the string literal, which is a constant array of characters, directly:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
if (fp != NULL) {
    fwrite("ABCDEFGH" + 1, 1, 6, fp);
    ...
}
```

`"ABCDEFGH" + 1` is the same as `&"ABCDEFGH"[1]`, the address of the second byte of the string. Arrays decay as pointers to their first element when used in expressions, except as the argument of `sizeof` and `_Alignof`.